# How to log messages from Hadoop?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, hadoop

How can I log messages from Hadoop Mapper (or Combiner/Reducer/whatever) so that I'd find these custom messages in Hadoop logs later?

```
public class GfimlMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, RawTerm>
{
    public void map(Object key, Text value, final Context context
                    ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
...
        Logger.log("HELLO THERE!"); // ???
...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you go to your cluster's  job tracker, then to your individual jobs you should get a list of tasks (maps and reduces) that were executed then there should be a link on the right to view the logs for that task. You can then see the stdout, syserr, and syslogs there I think. Check out stdout (not all of them will have an output but at least one will in my experience...)

Good luck!